# Mouse movement required to Click button

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am having an strange issue with clicking a button. When I click on a button, it is not registered as a click unless I move the mouse before I release the left button. Below is what I used in a new program to verify I didn't do something in the program I was working on.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 and build version 10.0.16212.1000

xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

c#:

```
namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button Clicked");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your mouse is good?

Comment: I can run your code in my pc.

Comment: Yes, I use the mouse/keyboard for my HTPC all the time.

Comment: The code will run correctly on a PC but compile it and load it to the raspberry pi I now have to move the mouse for the button to show the mouse was pressed down.

Comment: I test version 16237 on Raspberry Pi 3 and it works. Have you tried this version?